# Improve querydsl query with list entiy

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

When I excute this code above. It generate redundant query with Select * from. It too slow. Can anybody help me this.

> Hibernate: select * from ( select transactio0_.ID as col_0_0_, transactio0_.CREATED_DATE as col_1_0_, transactio0_.STATUS as col_2_0_, transactio0_.TYPE as col_3_0_, transactio0_.SERVICE_TYPE as col_4_0_, transactio0_.NOTE as col_5_0_, transactio0_.MOBILE_NO as col_6_0_, transactio0_.USER_ALIAS as col_7_0_, transactio0_.CUSTOMER_ID as col_8_0_, transactio0_.CLIENT_ID as col_9_0_, transactio0_.CIF_NO as col_10_0_, transactio0_.SENDER_ACCOUNT as col_11_0_, transactio0_.SENDER_BRANCH_CODE as col_12_0_, transactio0_.SENDER_POS_CODE as col_13_0_, transactio0_.BENE_ACCOUNT as col_14_0_, transactio0_.BENE_NAME as col_15_0_, transactio0_.BENE_BANK_CODE as col_16_0_, transactio0_.AMOUNT as col_17_0_, transactio0_.REAL_AMOUNT as col_18_0_, transactio0_.TOTAL_FEE as col_19_0_, transactio0_.TRACE_NO as col_20_0_, transactio0_.REF_NO as col_21_0_, transactio0_.RESPONSE_CODE as col_22_0_, transactio0_.AUTHEN_METHOD as col_23_0_, transactio0_.CHANNEL as col_24_0_, transactio0_.CCY as col_25_0_, transactio0_.QR_TRACE_NO as col_26_0_ from OMNI_TRANSACTIONS transactio0_ where transactio0_.CUSTOMER_ID=? and (transactio0_.CREATED_DATE between ? and ?) and (transactio0_.TYPE not in  (? , ?)) and (transactio0_.STATUS not in  (? , ?)) order by transactio0_.CREATED_DATE desc ) where rownum <= ?`your text`